# Send SMS via Twilio without Verification - RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twilio, twilio-click-to-call

Hey Guys I have an upgraded paid Twilio account and I'd like to send SMS without phone number verification through my Rails app.

Is there a way to do this?

Please advise

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The phone number verification for SMS is only a restriction to trial accounts. Once you have upgraded your account you will be able to send SMS messages to any number (though we recommend you get consent for that activity from the end user, of course).

If you are finding that you can't send messages without verifying the number and you have upgraded the app, then please get in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) and they will figure out what is wrong with your account.

Comment: is there any API or other resource to do this? I could not find anything that details out process to send SMS for unverified numbers using Rails or anything else

Comment: You use the [Message resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/send-messages) to send messages. There is a [Ruby gem available](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-ruby/) to make it easy to work with too.